# What is the twisting rate to reduce capacitance load on DC power transmission line?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, power-engineering

I need to carry dc (direct current) electrical power from a solar array to point of use.  I know that an undesirable capacitive load will develop if I just run the power and neutral wires parallel to each other for a long distance.  For this reason, the transmission wire pair would need to be twisted around each other to introduce an inductive load to offset the capacitive load.  This is a form of impedance balancing with the goal of net 0 reactive load, where reactance encompasses both inductance and capacitance.

I know there is a formula to calculate the wire twisting rate in twists per meter needed to cause enough inductance to zero out capacitance but I have had trouble finding it.  I think it is based on the total length of wire, size of wire, voltage, and width of insulation among other variables.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your source of this knowledge?  And where have you looked for the formulas?

Comment: So, when I installed my PV with 10 metres and approx 350V DC without a twisted pair cable - just "flat twin" of sufficient gauge and the next size above to reduce losses, it was signed off by the Inspection people as fine... I wonder if I really have an issue??

Comment: 10 meters no problem.  500 meters yes.